# i want to make ta.crossover(close(26), conversionline) but serial float is expected.want to make lagging span crossover tenkan,kinjun how can i do it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

//@version=5
strategy(title="Ichimoku Cloud", shorttitle="Ichimoku", overlay=true)

conversionPeriods = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")

basePeriods = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")

laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")

displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")

donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))

conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)

baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)

leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)

leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

plot(conversionLine, color=#2962FF, title="Conversion Line")

plot(baseLine, color=#B71C1C, title="Base Line")

plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")

p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=#A5D6A7,
title="Leading Span A")

p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=#EF9A9A,
title="Leading Span B")

fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.rgb(67, 160, 71, 90) : color.rgb(244, 67, 54, 90))

LongCondition = ta.crossover("Conversion Line", "Lagging Span")

ShortCondition = ta.crossover("Lagging Span", "Conversion Line")

strongbuy = ta.crossover("Lagging Span", "Base Line" )

strongsell = ta.crossover("Base Line", "Lagging Span")

if (LongCondition)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (ShortCondition)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use actual variables in crossover function instead of just writing their names, example below

```
//@version=5 
strategy(title="Ichimoku Cloud", shorttitle="Ichimoku", overlay=true)

conversionPeriods = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")

basePeriods = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")

laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")

displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")

donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))

conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)

baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)

leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)

leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

plot(conversionLine, color=#2962FF, title="Conversion Line")

plot(baseLine, color=#B71C1C, title="Base Line")

plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")

p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=#A5D6A7, title="Leading Span A")

p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=#EF9A9A, title="Leading Span B")

fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.rgb(67, 160, 71, 90) : color.rgb(244, 67, 54, 90))

LongCondition = ta.crossover(conversionLine, close[displacement])

ShortCondition = ta.crossover(close[displacement], conversionLine)

strongbuy = ta.crossover(close[displacement], baseLine )

strongsell = ta.crossover(baseLine, close[displacement])

if (LongCondition) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (ShortCondition) 
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```